# HTML bootstrap popover function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I was wondering for the popover given by bootstrap I have the following thing -

```
<a href="javascript: void(0)" id="member1" rel="popover" data-content="Co-President sample@uic.edu" data-original-title="Liz Sample"><img src="femaleprofilepicture2.jpg" class="img-polaroid"></a>
```

As of now when I click on the image I get both Co-President and sample@uic.edu on the same line. How do I make them appear on different lines.

Thanks

Comment: If you put the email, and title in the HTML content of the modal popup you can style them as needed, ie; one on each line. Wrap each in it's own div and style the email and title

Comment: How is your data content generated? is it dynamic?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

One way you can do this is by making the bootstrap popover content an html and setting html to true and provide a `<br/>` in between:

`data-content="Co-President <br/> sample@uic.edu"` and `data-html="true"`

i.e:

```
<a href="javascript: void(0)" id="member1" data-placement="bottom" rel="popover" data-content="Co-President <br/> sample@uic.edu" data-html="true" data-original-title="Liz Sample"><img src="femaleprofilepicture2.jpg" class="img-polaroid"/></a>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FBS7J/)**

*But it is always better to create the html content separately and populate it in the popover via the options.*

Something like this:

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript: void(0)" id="member1" data-contentwrapper=".mycontent"  rel="popover"><img src="femaleprofilepicture2.jpg" class="img-polaroid"/></a>

<div class="mycontent"> <!-- Here i define my content and add an attribute data-contentwrapper t0 a selector-->
    Co-President <br/> 
    sample@uic.edu
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('[rel=popover]').popover({
    html:true,
    placement:'bottom',
    content:function(){
        return $($(this).data('contentwrapper')).html();
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/szkrx/)

Comment: How safe is it to use html:true? I read this in the Boostrap docs: "Use text if you're worried about XSS attacks." See http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

Comment: @henrywright Basically, just don't inject unsanitized user input as HTML. In this case, if either of the display values are user inputted you would want to sanitize them separately and wrap them in your own HTML. HTML in and of itself isn't a concern.

Comment: if the html has input values like checkbox or texts, after closing the popover... all this data is cleared